# Showing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selected' of null

Tags: javascript

> Showing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selected' of null

```
    <select id="sorter" class="sorter-options">                                                             
    <option value="name">Product Name </option>
    <option value="price">Price</option>
    <option value="sort_by">Scale</option>
    </select>


   <script type="text/javascript">
    var val = '';    
    document.querySelector('#sorter [value="' + val + '"]').selected =  true;
   </script>
```

Comment: That's reasonable, considering there's no option with empty `value`. And what do you actually want to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an option is `val=''` and hence the selector returns null which is expected.

You could add a default empty option if you wish

```html
<select id="sorter" class="sorter-options">
    <option value="">Select options</option>             
    <option value="name">Product Name </option>
    <option value="price">Price</option>
    <option value="sort_by">Scale</option>
    </select>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    var val = '';    
    document.querySelector('#sorter [value="' + val + '"]').selected =  true;
   </script>
```

or else set the  value to an available option

```
 var val = 'price';    
 document.querySelector('#sorter [value="' + val + '"]').selected =  true;
```

or else provide a check for existence before checking the selected value.

```
 var val = '';    
 document.querySelector('#sorter [value="' + val + '"]') !== null? document.querySelector('#sorter [value="' + val + '"]').selected =  true: null;
```

or if you just wish to set the default value use defaultValue on select

```
<select id="sorter" class="sorter-options" defaultValue="price">
```

Answer (score 0):

`val` is an empty string whereas no `option` in this snippet have an empty string as value. Either create an option with value as empty string or set a predefined  value of `option` to `val`

```js
var val = 'price';
document.querySelector('#sorter [value="' + val + '"]').selected = true;
```

```html
<select id="sorter" class="sorter-options">                                                             
    <option value="name">Product Name </option>
    <option value="price">Price</option>
    <option value="sort_by">Scale</option>
    </select>
```